# CSS url path in additional chunk of Webpack can not be resolved correctly

Tags: webpack, code-splitting

I use Code Spliting feature of webpack to lazy load my angular app. I want to put some css in additional chunks to let the app lazy load these styles, but I found the url path in these css can not be resolved correctly. See the attachments below: 
[image: css-url-path-in-additional-chunk]
I have a background style for the h4 tag, but it can not be resolved correctly. At the same time, I have another img tag which use the same url on this page, the path is hard-coded in the src attribute, it can display correctly.
[image: url-in-html]

====== update ======

My Webpack config is here: [webpack.config.js](https://github.com/PinkyJie/angular1-webpack-starter/blob/master/webpack.config.js), the styl file mentioned in the question is here: [home-hero.styl](https://github.com/PinkyJie/angular1-webpack-starter/blob/master/source/app/components/home-hero/home-hero.styl), the header HTML file is here: [header.jade](https://github.com/PinkyJie/angular1-webpack-starter/blob/master/source/app/components/header/header.jade).

Another thing needs noting is that when I right click the url link in the first picture and choose "open in new link", I got the full url is `chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/assets/images/logo.46e065707257b2930a699c7cdacd7e86.png`, I think that's the main reason the picture can not be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the directory structure of your application this is hard to diagnose but I assume your CSS file is not in the same directory as your HTML file therefore the path `assets/images` is actually incorrect for the `background` property in the CSS file, but correct for the `<img>` tag in HTML.

You want the URL to have a slash as the start e.g `/assets/images` so it doesn't matter where your CSS files reside, they will always resolve form the root.

Try using [output.publicPath](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#outputpublicpath) in your Webpack config.

```
output: {
    publicPath: '/'
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Matt for your explaination, I add the config file and realted file link in the quesiton. Could you help me to check if there is any errors? I also tried the `publicPath` parameter, but I encontered a weird problem, Angular give me a "unpr" error.